# flash cs4: how can i change mouse cursor as if i'm on a button?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouse-cursor

I have some MovieClips that act like buttons, how can i do that when the user hovers on the movieclip, the mouse cursor will change to a hand or the default cursor when it hovers a button.

i don't want to create my own custom cursor, i want to use the default set of cursors that come with flash. thanks

using flash cs4, action script 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the property you are after is:

```
myMovieClip.buttonMode = true; //Use hand
myMovieClip.buttonMode = false; //Dont use hand
```

[see livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode)